# How to specify quantity of multiple model objects by form

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

So, im making my first pet project with django and im struggling with cart in my store.
Many guides are doing quantity in cart by buttons, but i want to enter a value by number form like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ2Xe.png)

So, i`ve come up with something like this:
views.py

```
def cart(request):



    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
        forms = []
        form = QuantityForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':

            for item in items:
                if item.quantity <= 0:
                    item.delete()
                else:
                    item_id = OrderItem.objects.get(id=item.id)
                    form = QuantityForm(request.POST, instance=item_id, initial={'quantity':item.quantity})

    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    context = {"items": items,
               "title": "Cart ◦ Shoppica",
               "order": order,
               "form":form,
               'cartItems': cartItems}

    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class QuantityForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ['quantity']
```

cart.html

```
          {% for item in items %}
          <tr class="even">
            <td valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td valign="middle"><a href="{% url 'Product' item.product.slug %}"><img src="{{ item.product.photo_front.url }}" width="60" height="60" alt="{{ item.product.title }}" /></a></td>
            <td valign="middle"><a href="{% url 'Product' item.product.slug %}"><strong>{{ item.product.title }}</strong></a></td>
            <td valign="middle">{{ form.quantity }}</td>
            <td valign="middle">${{ item.product.price }}<span class="s_currency s_after"> </span></td>
            <td valign="middle">${{ item.get_total }}<span class="s_currency s_after"></span></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

But when post form all quantities changes to quantity of last item.
Is there any ways to do it? Maybe using model form is a mistake, so if you know another ways feel free to answer, thanks.